# How to start Scala's sbt from a Makefile

Tags: scala, makefile, sbt

I am working on an Ubuntu 10.04 computer with 2 GB RAM and using `Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_26)` and `sbt 0.13.0-M2`.
I have created a Scala project with 20 source files and set it up to build with `sbt`.

If I run `sbt` interactively (start `sbt` and enter `compile`) everything works fine.

If I run `sbt` in batch mode, i.e. with the command line

```
$ sbt compile
```

everything works fine again.

Now I would like to run `sbt` within a more complex build (involving also other programming languages) and so I wanted to start `sbt` from a Makefile. My target looks like this:

```
SBT_JAVA_OPT=-J-Xss64m -J-Xms64m -J-Xmx1024m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

build-sbt:
    @sbt ${SBT_JAVA_OPT} compile
```

When invoking

```
$ make build-sbt
```

`sbt` prints the following error message:

```
[info] Set current project to ... (in build file:...)
[error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

I started `sbt` again and invoked

```
> last compile
```

but this gave no information.

I do not understand why starting `sbt` from a `Makefile` should make a difference. Does `make` impose some limitations on the memory one of its child processes can use?

So: is this a known problem? What it the correct way to start `sbt` from a `Makefile`?

Comment: Remove the `@` from your build-sbt recipe so that make prints the command line, and please paste the output into your question. (Also try running that full command manually.)

Comment: The command being run is `sbt -J-Xss64m -J-Xms64m -J-Xmx1024m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=256m compile`. As explained in my question, the command works perfectly when run manually, i.e. from the command-line.

Comment: `make` generally does not impose any limitations on memory usage of child processes. I asked about the specific command because the manual usage in your question said `sbt compile` without the other args. Can you verify that make is running the same `sbt` that you are running manually? i.e. use the absolute path to sbt both at the command line and in your Makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was reproducible on my debian machine. Please look at [this article](http://blog.egilh.com/2006/06/2811aspx.html) that talks about getting past this error by reducing memory allocated to the java VM:

> the more memory you give to the JVM the more likely you are to get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread exceptions when you have many threads.

I changed your Makefile as follows and the build succeeds:

```
SBT_JAVA_OPT=-J-Xss64m -J-Xms64m -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
#                                      ^^^ less memory

build-sbt:
    /usr/bin/sbt -verbose -debug ${SBT_JAVA_OPT} compile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Reducing the maximum memory to 512 MB solved the problem: I can build now!

Answer (score 0):

If you start using java 8, you will not even need to set max perm size anymore. Just an info in case you consider migrating to java 8